# error launching application for second time

Tags: android

I have this error i try to do a lot of things but i can't find the solution, when i start the application the first time i got the login activity and work fine, i close the application and start again, then the application crash, this is stack trace:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.app.Application.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
            at com.rrms.jrperera.rapidsentry.poco.AppManager.isConnected(AppManager.java:70)
            at com.rrms.jrperera.rapidsentry.activities.MainActivity.CheckInternetConnection(MainActivity.java:54)
            at com.rrms.jrperera.rapidsentry.activities.MainActivity.HandleSignIn(MainActivity.java:61)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
```

When i start the application from android studio this problem doesn't happen.
When i start the application in some point i start a service that it is running in background, the code for the methods: isConnected and CheckInternetConnection is implementing in a separate class that i'm using to manage all the application:

```
public class AppManager {

    public static final String SESSION_DATA = "com.rrms.jrperera.rapidsentry.MiOSSession";
    public static final String SERVICEURL = "https://xxxxxxx.com/RapidSentry/MiOSService.svc";//https://xxxxxxx.com/RapidSentry/MiOSService.svc//http://10.10.20.137/RapidMiOSApi/MiOSService.svc
    private static AppManager manager = null;
    private static Application application;
    private Boolean isServiceRunning = null;

    protected AppManager(Application app) {
        this.setApplication(app);
    }

    public static AppManager getManager(Application app) {
        if (manager == null) {
            manager = new AppManager(app);
        }
        return manager;
    }

    public Application getApplication() {
        return application;
    }

    public void setApplication(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        boolean connected = true;
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getApplication().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            connected = true;
        return connected;
    }
}
```

When the application crash i start again the application and again work fine.
Please any idea of what is going on with that?
this is the activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

protected AppManager manager = null;
protected EditText tbLoginUser = null;
protected EditText tbLoginPassword = null;
protected CheckBox cbLoginSaveCredentials = null;
protected ProgressBar pbLogin = null;
protected Button btSignIn = null;
protected Identity myIdentiy = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    isMyServiceRunning();
    tbLoginUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tb_login_user);
    tbLoginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tb_login_password);
    pbLogin = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loginProgressBar);
    pbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    btSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login_signin);
    cbLoginSaveCredentials = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb_login_save_credential);
    manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());
    if (manager.fileExistance("rapid-sentry-identity.txt")) {
        pbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new GetIdentityFile().execute();
    }
}

private boolean CheckInternetConnection() {
    manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());
    boolean isConnected = false;
    isConnected = manager.isConnected();
    return isConnected;
}

public void HandleSignIn(View view) {
    pbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());
    if (!CheckInternetConnection()) {
        Toast.makeText(manager.getApplication().getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_internet_connection, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        String user = tbLoginUser.getText().toString();
        String password = tbLoginPassword.getText().toString();
        new Login().execute(user, password);
    }


}

private void SaveSharePreferences() {
    manager.SaveSharedIdentityObject(myIdentiy);
}

private class Login extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String result = null;
        try {
            Identity identity = manager.VerifyLogin(params[0], params[1]);
            myIdentiy = identity;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if (cbLoginSaveCredentials.isChecked()) {
            new SaveIdentityFile().execute(myIdentiy.getIdentityUser(), myIdentiy.getIdentityPassword());
        }
        if (myIdentiy == null) {
            Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);
            tbLoginUser.startAnimation(shake);
            tbLoginPassword.startAnimation(shake);
            Toast.makeText(manager.getApplication().getApplicationContext(), R.string.login_error_login, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            SaveSharePreferences();
            pbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent intentGateway = new Intent(getApplication(), GatewayActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentGateway);
        }
    }
}

private class GetIdentityFile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String[] ident;
        try {
            ident = manager.RetrieveIdentityFromFile();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ident = null;
        }
        return ident;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] aVoid) {
        if (aVoid != null) {
            new Login().execute(aVoid[0], aVoid[1]);
        }
    }
}

private class SaveIdentityFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            manager.SaveIdentityFile(params[0], params[1]);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ((UpdateShareDataService.class).getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Intent intentService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateShareDataService.class);
            stopService(intentService);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: i swear to god if i see another suggestion for "potential duplicate ' what is a null pointer exception'" im going to go ballistic

Comment: I don't got you, do you think that my question is duplicate, because i don't find the solution in any other post here, i know that null exception is a common exception but... is not my particularly case.

Comment: You probably initialize something in onCreate which is automatically unloaded in onPause. you should initialize this in onResume too. Share your Activites code for further help.

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera im not complaining about your question at all. Since there's a nullpointer in the stacktrace lots of users on Stack Overflow like to immediately tag the question as a duplicate. My comment was more of a warning not to do that (because it's 99% of the time wrong),

Comment: @ iismathwizard 28 thanks, you are right in your suggestion.

Comment: `manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication()); ` .Why you are calling above line two times ? @JoseRaulPerera

Comment: @Soham you are right i'm calling twice because i thought that for some reason i have a null on the Appmanager the application attribute but, if i erased it is the same

Comment: @Mike M i think that i'm initializing the application when in the onCreate i'm saying: manager = AppManager.getManager(getApplication());

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera .Have you created any class that extends `Application`.

Comment: @Soham no i don't have created any class extending Application

Comment: I see that the problem occur if the i start the service, if the user don't use the activity where the service start running then the application don't show any problem, by the way the service run in background and it is using a Appmanager variable too, this could be an idea...

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer for this problem, i was running a service in background pooling data, but in this service i was using the application context, when the application was close the service was restarting several times. The solution was call the method onDestroy() of every activity to be sure that when you close the application the service will destroy too using stopService. Thanks to all!!

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if ((UpdateShareDataService.class).getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            Intent intentService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateShareDataService.class);
            stopService(intentService);
        }
    }
    refreshData.cancel();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```